# Post multipart/form-data in C# to upload photos on facebook

Tags: facebook, file-upload, web-parts, facebook-c#-sdk

I have closely looked into each of the links on stackoverlow and tested them with facebook , but none of them is working for facebook. It throws an error each time (improper format). Please help me , I need a facebook developer in C# to help me out.

Comment: Can you at least post the code you are using, and describe the errors you are getting? - otherwise it is very difficult for anybody to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have samples on uploading video and photos in a Facebook nuget sample package.

Can you try this and check out the code please?

```
Install-Package Facebook.Sample
```